# python can encode to utf-8 but can't decode

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, decode

The Code Below Can Encode A String To Utf-8 :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

str = 'ورود'
print(str.encode('utf-8'))
```

That Prints:

```
b'\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf'
```

But I can't Decode This String With This Code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

str = b'\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf'
print(str.decode('utf-8'))
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(str.decode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Please Help Me ...

#### Edit

From the answers switched to a byte string:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

str = b'\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf'
print(str.decode('utf-8'))
```

Now the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(str.decode('utf-8'))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: `str = b'\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf'; print(str.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: I have tested it in my interpreter, it worked.

Comment: it works for me. check if your python is installed

Comment: Which version of python? python3 and python2 different way treat with unicode chars.

Comment: You should precise which version of python you use, as python2 and python3 have a really different comportment with string managment

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: i uses python 3.4 on windows 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using Python 3.X.  You `.encode()` Unicode strings (`u'xxx'` or `'xxx'`).  You `.decode()` byte strings `b'xxxx'`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

s = b'\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf'
#   ^
#   Need a 'b'
#
print(s.decode('utf-8'))
```

Note your terminal may not be able to display the Unicode string.  Mine Windows console doesn't:

```
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:35:05) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = b'\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf'
>>> #   ^
... #   Need a 'b'
... #
... print(s.decode('utf-8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "D:\dev\Python33x64\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>
```

But it *does* do the decode.  `'\uxxxx'` represents a Unicode code point.

```
>>> s.decode('utf-8')
'\u0648\u0631\u0648\u062f'
```

My PythonWin IDE supports UTF-8 and can display the characters:

```
>>> s = b'\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf'
>>> print(s.decode('utf-8'))
ورود
```

You can also write the data to a file and display it in an editor that supports UTF-8, like Notepad.  since your original string is already UTF-8, just write it to a file directly as bytes.  `'wb'` opens the file in binary mode and the bytes are written as is:

```
>>> with open('out.txt','wb') as f:
...     f.write(s)
```

If you have a Unicode string, you can write it as UTF-8 with:

```
>>> with open('out.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
...     f.write(u)  # assuming "u" is already a decoded Unicode string.
```

P.S. `str` is a built-in type.  Don't use it for variable names.

Python 2.x works differently.  `'xxxx'` is a byte string and `u'xxxx'` is a Unicode string, but you still `.encode()` the Unicode string and `.decode()` the byte string.

Comment: What does `not work` mean?  Show an error message.  Most likely, your terminal cannot display the characters you are trying to print.  Are you getting a `UnicodeEncodeError`?  That is the terminal complaining that it doesn't support the characters you are printing.

Comment: thats the error :  File "D:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: cha
racter maps to <undefined>

Comment: Whatever IDE you are using is mapping to code page 1252 (US English Windows).  It can't display those foreign characters.  Use an IDE that supports UTF-8.  See my updated example.

Comment: yes your code can decode but can't print ... How i can save this decoded string to a file with python ?

Comment: It can print if you use a UTF-8 IDE, or as you suggest you can write it to a file and open it in Notepad, which supports UTF-8.

Comment: thancks,but your code don't convert byte to string ! how can i convert str to string ?

Comment: Piping the putput to a text editor worked for me on windows console/Notepad++. `py so.py > test.txt`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a first class unicode type that you can use in place of the plain bytestring
str type. It’s easy, once you accept the need to explicitly convert between a
bytestring and a Unicode string:

```
>>> persian_enter = unicode('\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf', 'utf8')
>>> print persian_enter
ورود
```

Python 2 had two global functions to coerce objects into strings: unicode() to coerce them into Unicode strings, and str() to coerce them into non-Unicode strings. Python 3 has only one string type, [Unicode strings](http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html#divingin), so the str() function is all you need. (The unicode() function no longer exists.)

read more about [reading and writing unicode data](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)

Comment: whats your python version ?

Comment: Python 2 had two global functions to coerce objects into strings: unicode() to coerce them into Unicode strings, and str() to coerce them into non-Unicode strings. Python 3 has only one string type, Unicode strings, so the str() function is all you need. (The unicode() function no longer exists.)

Comment: yep, so , alongside the good answer by @Mark i suggest read more about unicode in `python3.x` in that link i added to my answer !

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
str = b'\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xaf'
print(str.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: his original code works, think he doesnt have python installed properly. (on mac it does)

Comment: no this code not work... i runned this on windows 7 and python 3.4