# Reading text file into dic file results in incomplete dic file

Tags: python

The following file 2016_01_22_Reps.txt   is a list of expanded contractions that I want to put into a python dic file; 
“can't":"cannot","could've":"could have","could've":"could have","didn't":"did not","doesn't":"does not", “don't":"do not"," hadn't":"had not", "hasn't":"has not","haven't":"have not","I'll":"I will","I'm":"I am","I've":"I have","isn't":"is not","I'll":"I 
Note that the contents are a single line, not multiple lines.

My code is as follows;

```
reps = open('2016_01_22_Reps.txt', 'r')
Reps1dic={}
for line in reps:
    x=line.split(",")   
    a=x[0]  
    b=x[1]  
    c=len(b)-1  
    b=b[0:c]        
    Reps1dic[a]=b   
print (Reps1dic)
```

The output to Reps1dic stops after  first two pairs of contractions. Contents are as follows;

`{‘2016_01_22Reps = {“can\’t”:”cannot”‘ : ‘”could\’ve”:”could have’}`

Instructions and explanation of why the complete file contents are not written to the dic file will be most appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the help  !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your values are all on one line, so your `for line in reps` only goes through the one iteration. Do something like this:

```
with open('2016_01_22_Reps.txt', 'r') as reps:
    Reps1dic={}
    contents = reps.read()
    pairs = contents.split(',')
    for pair in pairs:
        parts = pair.split(':')
        a = parts[0].replace('"', '').strip()
        b = parts[1].replace('"', '').strip()
        Reps1dic[a] = b
print(Reps1dic)
```

where you split the line and then iterate over that list instead of the lines in the file. I also used the [`with` keyword](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to open your file - it's much better practice.

Comment: When I try to run your code, I am seeing this weird error. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(Reps1dic)
  File "....\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7Slim\python-3.4.3\lib\en
codings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 63-64: character m
aps to <undefined>` strange thing is the character position error changes each time I run it.

Comment: Ah ok, the issue was [Windows console not being able to display a unicode string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670103/python-can-encode-to-utf-8-but-cant-decode). I think it is the pesky "smart quotes" which are located here ` "“can't": 'cannot', "“don't": 'do not'`. @RJS, I would strip them out of your text file to save yourself a headache. Otherwise @wilbur's solution works.

Comment: Yeah, I had a similar issue, but I assumed it was just my copy/pasting and that the original txt file didn't include the smart quotes.